# Changing API version on facebook app dashboard

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, upgrade

The Facebook app dashboard shows that my graph api is set to version 2.3.

When I load the php sdk, I set the default graph version to 2.4.

My question is how do I get the dashboard to show version 2.4? I am being asked to upgrade to 2.3, and I'm not sure what else I need to do.

Comment: _"The Facebook app dashboard shows that my graph api is set to version 2.3."_ - no, it doesn’t. Move your cursor over it, and it will tell you that this shows what the _minimum_ API version your app can use is. // Your app should _specify_ the version in the API calls it is making. If you have not done that in your code yet, you can also override the API version for test users.